# Block-Closures and ternary operator for enumeration of NSArray with dynamic code

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, dynamic-code

I have no clue if what I am trying to do is possible or not. I am not experienced with blocks, just read a few tutorials, and really like the idea.
My class AppointmentView.h (and m) is extending a ViewController. It contains a few properties which are members of another Class Appointment, which in turn has a few NSArrays.
For the purpose of creating a grouped tableview, I check the values of the arrays, and then copy appropriately values that will be displayed (nothing too fancy or complicated).
Normally I would go with if-else statements, and control appropriately, however after looking at blocks, it got me thinking if the following is doable:

```
[self setOutcomes: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        ^{ return [myAppointment.CANCELED isEqualToString:@"NO"] == YES ? 
                                                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Not Cancelled"] :
                                                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Cancelled"]; },
                        ^{ return [myAppointment.CANCELED isEqualToString:@"NO"] == YES ?
                                                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"No Cancellation reason"] :
                                                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:myAppointment.CANCREASON]; },
                        ^{ return [myAppointment EVENTS].length > 0 ?
                                                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:myAppointment.EVENTS] :
                                                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"No Events"]; },
                        ^{ return [myAppointment SUMMARY].length > 0 ?
                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:myAppointment.SUMMARY] :
                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"No Summary"]; },
                        nil]];
```

This code compiles fine, but it crashes when run. My understanding is that this is wrong, because I am telling the enumeration to execute a piece of code every time. So this is not what I want.
Then I tried the following:

```
   [self setOutcomes: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [[NSString alloc] initWithString: (NSString *) ^(void){ 
                                                                        return [myAppointment.CANCELED isEqualToString:@"NO"] == YES ?
                                                                                                        @"Not Cancelled" : @"Cancelled"; }],
                        [[NSString alloc] initWithString: (NSString *) ^(void){ 
                                                                        return [myAppointment.CANCELED isEqualToString:@"NO"] == YES ? 
                                                                                                        @"No Cancellation reason" : myAppointment.CANCREASON; }],
                        [[NSString alloc] initWithString: (NSString *) ^(void){ 
                                                                        return [myAppointment.EVENTS isEqualToString:@""] == YES ? 
                                                                                                        myAppointment.EVENTS : @"No Events"; }],
                        [[NSString alloc] initWithString: (NSString *) ^(void){ 
                                                                        return [myAppointment.SUMMARY isEqualToString:@""] == YES ?
                                                                                                        myAppointment.SUMMARY : @"No Summary"; }],
                        nil]];
```

Which although it compiles fine, crashes with the following error:

> -[**NSMallocBlock** length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6bd68f0

I also tried typedefining a generic method which I could use, but didnt help either.
So, I was wondering, is this possible ? I know that for this piece of code, I could simply use an if-else (like I normally would) and be done with it, but other circumstances, such a dynamic code generation option would be extremely useful.

I got the feeling that either NSString does not know how to handle this, and I should therefore extend it with an options lets say

> initWithBlock:

Or I am missing something else here. Or it may just be not possible.... (?)

PS: I have just seen NSArray's enumerateUsingBlock: method, but I am not certain if this would serve my purpose in this case, as each entry in the array is completely different from the other, and a specific block would not fit the criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make simple choices in the initializer you don't need blocks.

```
[NSArray initWithObjects:
         ([myAppointment.CANCELED isEqualToString:@"NO"] ? @"Not Cancelled" : @"Cancelled"),
         ([myAppointment.CANCELED isEqualToString:@"NO"] ? @"No Cancellation reason" : myAppointment.CANCREASON),
         nil];
```

Use parens to enclose the ?: operator.

---

**Updated to answer question of how to define and invoke a block at same spot**

This unit test worked for me:

```
- (void)testBlockNow
{
    BOOL X = ^{ return YES; }();
    STAssertTrue(X, nil);
}
```

That's simple: `^{ … }` to define the block, then `()` to invoke the block.

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine. And in this case, this is sufficient.
However, in more complex cases, where a ternary operator is not enough, how could I use a block which is defined on the spot, instead of the ternary operator ?

Comment: @Alex: there is a GCC extension that will allow you to include an arbitrarily complex block of statements as an expression: gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html I think this will do what you want without messing with blocks when you don't need it.

Comment: @newacct Thank you that is very useful, although non-block related, it captures what I was trying to do with blocks.

Comment: @newacct yo, bro, make those links **hyper*, yo..   that shit's crazy hard to select!  markdown, biznitches!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store blocks in an array, but you will need to be clever about it.

```
typedef (void)(^X)();

X block1 = ^{ … };
X block2 = ^{ … };
X block3 = ^{ … };

NSArray *array = [NSArray initWithObjects:
                  [[block1 copy] autorelease],
                  [[block2 copy] autorelease],
                  [[block3 copy] autorelease],
                  nil];
```

Comment: This is quite useful, but not really what I am after, as in this scenario you are using different block for each case. I would rather not define anything, but implement the block on the fly as values are being filled in.

Comment: I not really sure what you are asking for. If you want to add and remove blocks from the array dynamically, this is possible. Use an NSMutableArray with -addObject: and -removeObject:. If you want to create new blocks at runtime, this is not really possible in a compiled language.

Comment: Not exactly, I want the compiled code (the blocks) to dynamically generate the values for the strings, depending on other variables. I am probably doing something wrong with the parameters and pointers, as the error I am getting seems to indicate that no selector is set for some instance. Will try your example now.

Comment: Oh, then you don't need blocks. I'll post a different answer.